# Unable to access parent entity attributes by ID

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, twig

I am trying to work out why I can't access the *name* (or any attribute) of the parent entity of my `Category` entity. My view works fine and displays all the attributes other than the parent information.

What I am looking for is the name (i.e. "Interior") of the parent, rather than the ID. But I can't seem to access it.

```
namespace AyrshireMinis\CarBundle\Entity;

class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $parent_id;

    /**
     * @var Category
     */
    protected $parent;

    public function __construct() {}

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getParentId()
    {
        return $this->parent_id;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return new self($this->parent_id);
    }
}
```

My Doctrine entity mapping:

```
fields:
    parent_id:
        type: integer
        length: 11
        nullable: true
```

In my Twig template I am attempting to pull out the parent category's name like this:

```
<td>
   {{ category.parent.name }}
</td>
```

However, I get no error but no category name either.

This is a brief view of my SQL GUI:

[image]

The table is hierarchical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by removing the `parent_id` from my ORM mapping and replacing it with this:

```
manyToOne:
    parent:
        targetEntity: AyrshireMinis\CarBundle\Entity\Category
        inversedBy: children
```

Then added these member variables to my `Category` entity class:

```
/**
* @var Category
*/
private $children;

/**
* @var Category
*/
private $parent;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function getParent()
{
    return new self($this->parent_id);
}
```

What you are doing here is creating a new category with all properties blank. Take a look at the [symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations) and [doctrine](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) documentation to learn how to create relationships properly.

Comment: OK. I'm reading that page just now, is there an example of what I am trying to do? The classic "category and product" doesn't really fit my needs as the `parent_id` of a child category references a category in the same table.

Comment: Thanks, the links you posted were interesting but they did not have the solution to the question I posted.

Comment: You're welcome. I was about to suggest for you to look at the One-To-Many, Self-referencing on the doctrine documentation but it seems that you figured it out by yourself.